# Method to get non-base units?

Tags: labview

Is there a method of using the exponent properties of LabView units for carrying custom units?  For example I would find it convenient to use milli-Amperes instead of Amperes in my data wires.

My first attempt at doing so looks like this, but trying to get the value out at the end gives me nothing.[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I would find it convenient to use milli-Amperes instead of Amperes in my data wires

For a wire, it's not possible, and it's not a problem, here's why:

I'm afraid what you want make little sense, since you're milli-Amperes instead of Amperes refers to *representing* your data, while a wire is just raw data. Adding the milli- to a floating point changes the exponent, not the mantissa, so there's no loss or gain of precision in the value that your number carries.

Now if we talk about an indicator which is technically a display of the wire value, you change the unit from "A" to "mA" to have the display you want.

Finally, in your attempt with "set numeric info", the `-3` factor added next to Amperes means the unit is `A^-3`, not `mA`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data that don't use units, however than you will loose your automatic check of the units.
For display properties you can tweak the [display format](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361K-01/lvconcepts/format_specifier_syntax/) to show different outputs:
[image: Display in mA]

This format string is constructed as following:
% *numeric*
^ *engineering notation, exponents in multiples of three*
# *no trailing zeros*
_6 *six significat digits*
e *scientific notation (1e1 for instance)*

Answer (score 0):

The prefix is the best way to affect the presentation of the value on a specific front panel.

When passing data from VI to VI, the prefix is not passed, and the data uses the base ( Amps, Volts, etc...)

In my example below, the unitless value 3 is assigned units of Amp in mA.vi. The front panel indicator is set to show units of mA.

In Watts.vi I multiply the Amps OUT of mA.vi by a constant of 9V and the result is wired to the indicator x*y.

x*y has units of W and I changed the prefix to k for presentation.

The NI forums have several threads that report certain functions (square and square root specifically) can cause unit errors or broken wires. Most folks don't even know the units capability exists, and most that do have tried and abandoned them. :)

[image]